# When i will know the my module accepted or not from prestashop addons?

Tags: module, prestashop, add-on

I just add the my module to prestashop addons page. On the prestashop seller account page product status is "Offline", marketing and technical statuses are "Waiting"

Did anyone know how long time it will take usually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have more than 40 modules validated on the addons, usually it takes between 48H and 2 weeks to have the technical validation, if no error is to wait a few days more for the validation Marketing.

Do you pass your module in the online validator?

If you need advice we are at your disposal

Regards

Comment: Yes validation is passed.  Just readme document is simple and quick write.

Answer (score 1):

Technical validation is made before marketing. In my experience technical validation takes 10 days average. If your module pass validation successfully, you will receive a notification email. If you has some issues to fix in your module (Addons Team is very exquisite with now modules) you will receive an email too.
After that you must wait for marketing validation.

You must wait. That's all you can do.

Good luck.